# Shopify API How to update Inventory Level via the Shopify API Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-api

Anyone know how to update a variants inventory level via the Shopify API Gem?

I've tried everything I can think of, including checking out the Gem specs and no luck.

I have the correct `location_id` as well as `inventory_item_id` AND the `read_inventory, write_inventory` scopes. As well as a valid `session`

I've tried the following with no luck

```
payload = {"location_id":xxxxxx, "inventory_item_id":xxxxxx, "available":144}
```

Then:

```
level = ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.find(:all, params: payload)
level.set
level.connect
level.adjust
level.save

ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.set(payload)
ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.new(payload)
ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.create(payload)
ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.adjust(payload)
ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.update(payload)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whelp, I figured it out. Would have been nice if it was documented somewhere.. A boy can dream

But you first have to create an instance of `InventoryLevel` like so:

```
payload = {"location_id":xxx, "inventory_item_id":xxx}
level = ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.new(payload)
```

And then set the inventory on that instance like this:

```
level.set(69)
```